# How do I vertically align text & image in a table cell

Tags: php, html, css

So my problem can be seen in this picture:
[image: text not alligned]

How do I make every cell have the text at the same height? The last `<th>` (text+img) drags it down for some reason.

My css:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  border-collapse: collapse
}

.table th {
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  background: 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
}

.table th.gold {
  color: #ffdd45
}

.table td {
  padding: .7em .5em .6em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  background: #222;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table class="table rate" style="margin-top: 0;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Number 1</th>
      <th class="gold">Number 2</th>
      <th>text+img</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="players-table1">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/user/9842394892389" class="username">
          <img src="piclink" alt="Аvatar"><span>user0</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="bold gold">500</td>
      <td style="width:10%"><i>35x<img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" style="width:55%;height:10%"/></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/user/9842394892389" class="username">
          <img src="piclink" alt="Аvatar"><span>user</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="bold gold">400</td>
      <td style="width:10%"><i>35x<img src="piclink" style="width:55%;height:10%"/></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/user/9842394892389" class="username">
          <img src="piclink" alt="Аvatar"><span>user2</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="bold gold">300</td>
      <td style="width:10%"><i>35x<img src="piclink" style="width:55%;height:10%"/></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">4</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/user/9842394892389" class="username">
          <img src="piclink" alt="Аvatar"><span>user2</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="bold gold">300</td>
      <td style="width:10%"><i>35x<img src="piclink"/></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this:

> 1. Decreasing the height of the `image`(which is what I did in answer), this was `10%` before and I made it as `5%`. The `td` content was pushing down due to that.
> 2. If you don't want to decrease the height of the image then you have to increase the height of the each `row` so that the height can easily fit-in.

so call is yours what to choose.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  border-collapse: collapse
}

.table th {
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  background: 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
}

.table th.gold {
  color: #ffdd45
}

.table td {
  padding: .7em .5em .6em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  background: #222;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table rate" style="margin-top: 0;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Number 1</th>
      <th class="gold">Number 2</th>
      <th>text+img</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="players-table1">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/user/9842394892389" class="username">
          <img src="piclink" alt="Аvatar"><span>user0</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="bold gold">500</td>
      <td style="width:10%"><i>35x<img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" style="width:55%;height:5%"/></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">2</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/user/9842394892389" class="username">
          <img src="piclink" alt="Аvatar"><span>user</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="bold gold">400</td>
      <td style="width:10%"><i>35x<img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" style="width:55%;height:5%"/></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">3</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/user/9842394892389" class="username">
          <img src="piclink" alt="Аvatar"><span>user2</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="bold gold">300</td>
      <td style="width:10%"><i>35x<img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" style="width:55%;height:5%"/></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">4</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/user/9842394892389" class="username">
          <img src="piclink" alt="Аvatar"><span>user2</span></a>
      </td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="bold gold">300</td>
      <td style="width:10%"><i>35x<img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" style="width:55%;height:5%"/></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The 1st option doesn't work very well for me, so I decided to go with the second one, but for some reason when I add `height: 50%` or something similar to `.table tr` it doesn't change anything, only `height:70px` makes it larger, I guess the height is already 100%, but I dont know if hardcoding `px` is a good idea?

Comment: Correct your understanding is right on this, the `td` will have its own 100% height so you can provide it in `px` and increase it's height and get this done, I don't think so you have to worry about hardcoding pixel. Let me know if you need any help on this.